# Flutter: Listening and writing to a socket in a single stateful widget

Tags: flutter, sockets, listen

I haven't worked on a flutter application in a while and haven't ever worked on a socket level application.  I am attempting to learn how to make a single stateful widget listen to  a socket.  The widget can easily write data to the socket.

I'm trying to learn an approach to the problem so I can sort out how to organize my application.

Edit:  I have a sloppy version so it is more clear what I want to accomplish.

```
// Assume this will be stored in some BLoC 
// that will be available to any widget that needs it.
Socket socket;

void main() async {
  socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.139.194', 80);
  //can write to client with socket.write("...");

  socket.listen(handleClient);
  // handleClient takes care of responding to message from client

  runApp(MyApp(sock));
}

void handleClient(Uint8List data) {
  // Show the address and port of the client
  print('Connection from '
    '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');

  // Show what the client said
  print("client listen  : ${String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");

  // Send acknowledgement to client
  socket.write("Hello from simple server!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Socket.connect()` to connect a socket for client side and `ServerSocket.bind()` to listen incoming connections for server side. You can send data over socket by using `socket.write(message);`, and listen response by using `socket.listen();`.

example client code :

```
Socket.connect("localhost", 9999).then((socket) {
  print('client connected : ${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');

  socket.listen((data) {
    print("client listen  : ${String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");
  }, onDone: () {
    print("client done");
    socket.destroy();
  });

  socket.write(message);
});
```

example server code :

```
  void listen() {
    ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 9999).then((ServerSocket server) {
      server.listen(handleClient);
    });
  }

  void handleClient(Socket client) {
    print('server incoming connection from ${client.remoteAddress.address}:${client.remotePort}');
    client.listen((data) {
      print("server listen  : ${String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");
      setState(() {
        _incomingMessage = String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      print("server done");
    });
    client.close();
  }
```

please refer this : https://jamesslocum.com/blog/post/67566023889

you can find full source code on github for [client](https://github.com/utariddev/socket_client) and [server](https://github.com/utariddev/socket_server)

---

**Update** : If you want to use same widget can listen and write you can refer this code. you should start to listen socket in constructor.

example code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    listen();
  }

  void socketSend(String message) {
    Socket.connect("localhost", 9999).then((socket) {
      print('client connected : ${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');

      socket.listen((data) {
        print("client listen  : ${String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");
      }, onDone: () {
        print("client done");
        socket.destroy();
      });

      socket.write(message);
    });
  }

  void listen() {
    ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 9999).then((ServerSocket server) {
      server.listen(handleClient);
    });
  }

  void handleClient(Socket client) {
    print('server incoming connection from ${client.remoteAddress.address}:${client.remotePort}');
    client.listen((data) {
      print("server listen  : ${String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");
    }, onDone: () {
      print("server done");
    });
    client.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myController = TextEditingController();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("socket test"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(controller: myController),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => socketSend(myController.text), child: const Text("Send")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also port `80` is reserved port for `HTTP`. You should not use this port for testing.

Comment: I must not have been clear,  I want one single stateless widget to be able to read and write from/to the same socket I will modify my question.

Comment: hi @Nefarious , I updated my answer. please check.